# Ionic 3 view PDF in content view with external URL

Tags: pdf, ionic-framework, ionic3, inappbrowser

The application has to show invoice PDF inside `<div>` which is currently rendered in Webapp itself.

For example :
The web app already has the PDF generation functionality which generates by clicking on `generate_pdf` function.
I want to show the same PDF by using the same function which is currently available for the public.

Example URL:

```
http://URL/index.php/pulic/view/generate_invoice_pdf/Smgr4NX7yiWfu3J6qhdtRzF9lVT0kLs2
```

I have tried `InAppBrowser` however, it opens up outside the app just want to show inside the app.
`DocumentViewer` is not supported since it does not contain .pdf in URL

Comment: Can you try with iframe?

Comment: yes, I did but it won't work on android device.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone who needs the solution

I use `fileTranfer` to download the file and `File` to show it on the device.